# Simplified form for $\int_{\lambda}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty e^{-(s+t)}(st)^{x-1}\ln \frac{s}{t} ds dt$

Tags: probability, density-function, multiple-integral

I'm interested in a simplification for the integral given by
$$\int_{\lambda}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty e^{-(s+t)}(st)^{x-1}\ln \frac{s}{t} ds dt$$

which arises as a definition for the density of a random variable following the "continuous Poisson" distribution.

Comment: Try integrating by parts to get rid of the $ln\frac{s}{t}$ term.

Answer (score 2):

There's not much simplification you can really do, but there is a nice connection to the Wronskian determinant.

Let
$$F(x)=\int_{\lambda}^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-s-t}(st)^{x-1}\log(s/t)\mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t$$
First separate the log-
$$=\int_\lambda^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-s-t}(st)^{x-1}\left(\log s-\log t\right)\mathrm ds\mathrm dt$$
Which we break up, and then separate variables.
$$=\int_\lambda^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}\int_0^\infty e^{-s}s^{x-1}\log(s)\mathrm ds\mathrm dt-\int_{\lambda}^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}\log t\int_0^\infty e^{-s}s^{x-1}\mathrm ds\mathrm dt$$
Recognizing the gamma function and its derivative, as well as the upper incomplete Gamma function, this is
$$=\Gamma'(x)\gamma_{\text{up}}(x,\lambda)-\Gamma(x)~\partial_x\gamma_{\text{up}}(x,\lambda)$$
This is in fact the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) of the two:
$$F(x)=W(\gamma_{\text{up}},\Gamma)(x)$$
So there are certain ways you can relate it to solutions of second order linear ODEs.

Comment: [+1] Good observation that I hadn't done when I arrived at the same expression.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer.

Here is a way to convert the double integral into two simple integrals (that are numerically more tractable).

Write the initial integral

$$\int_{\lambda}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty e^{-(s+t)}(st)^{x-1}\ln \frac{s}{t} ds dt$$

into

$$\int_{\lambda}^\infty e^{-s}s^{x-1}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}(\ln s - \ln t) dt ds$$

$$=\int_{\lambda}^\infty e^{-s}s^{x-1}\ln s 
 \underbrace{\left(\int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt\right)}_{\Gamma(x) \ \text{independent of} s} ds - \int_{\lambda}^\infty e^{-s}s^{x-1}\underbrace{\left(\int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}\ln t dt\right)}_{I=\Gamma^{\ \prime}(x)} ds$$

For the proof of $I=\Gamma'(x)$, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2836661).

Sorry to stop there, wishing you further advances by different techniques (integration by parts, etc...)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try integration by parts, but this is an excellent start.

Comment: I imagine that you have read [this](http://ac.inf.elte.hu/Vol_039_2013/137_39.pdf).

Comment: Yeah, that's where I found this! I'm trying to get something that will be nicer to compute numerically.

Comment: Somewhat related: "THE TWO-PARAMETER POISSON–DIRICHLET DISTRIBUTION DERIVED FROM A STABLE SUBORDINATOR"  Jim Pitman and Marc Yor